# p:splitButton menu item to launch a p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am trying to have a `p:splitButton` `p:menuItem` launch a `p:dialog`. I have the following

```
<h:form>
    <p:splitButton value="Action" icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-s">
        <p:menuitem value="New label" icon="ui-icon-newwin">
            <p:commandLink onclick="PF('dlg1').show();"/>
        </p:menuitem>
    </p:splitButton>

    <p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true" height="100">
        <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

I can't however see the "New label" menu item in the list. Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix it like so

```
<h:form>
    <p:splitButton value="Action" icon="ui-icon-circle-triangle-s">
        <p:menuitem value="New label" icon="ui-icon-newwin" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" />
    </p:splitButton>

    <p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true" height="100">
        <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```